# PHP DateTime локальное время

Tags: php, datetime

Подскажите как установить локальное время в библиотеке DateTime

Ставлю так $user_datetime = new DateTime('Asia/Yekaterinburg');

Этого достаточно чтобы получать правильную дату (день недели и тп) через $user_datetime->getTimestamp() и date()

Comment: И еще например же день недели у американцев начинается с воскресения отсчет. Т.е. в зависимости от часового пояса указанного при инициализации класса будет выбираться отчет? А если в пояс +5 например входит другая страна?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Дата/время в заданной временной зоне.
$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Yekaterinburg'));

// Порядковый номер дня недели в соответствии со стандартом ISO-8601
// от 1 (понедельник) до 7 (воскресенье)
$dn = $date->format('N');
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php